# How can I reverse values in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Right now I am using your [library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to display some data obtained from two API calls in a Horizontal BarChart. I am saving the values in two ArrayLists of BarEntries and then drawing the chart.
My issue is that I would like to reverse the order of the bars, so its descending from highest to lowest.
Is it possible to change the order, after the entries have been added to the ArrayList of BarEntries?So i have done reverse,but some issues the values are not proper.
Please look on my code,

```
     class Top10UsersChartDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String response = null;
            try {
                response = apiDetails.Top10UsersChartFunc(params[0], params[1]);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            try {
                JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject(s);
                String status = resObj.getString("status");
                String Month = resObj.getString("Month");
                Log.e("status", status);
                Log.e("Month", Month);
                leaderBoardTV.setText("BEER LEADER BOARD - "+Month);
                if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
                    JSONArray userdataDetailsArray = resObj.getJSONArray("userdata");
                    Log.e("userdataDetailsArray::", userdataDetailsArray + "");
                    for (int j = 0; j < userdataDetailsArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject CampaignDetailsArrayObject = userdataDetailsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        String userId = CampaignDetailsArrayObject.getString("userId");
                        String UserName = CampaignDetailsArrayObject.getString("UserName");
                        String CountRunning = CampaignDetailsArrayObject.getString("Count");
                        String position=CampaignDetailsArrayObject.getString("position");
                        Log.e("CountRunning",CountRunning+"");
                        Log.e("CountRunning1",Float.parseFloat(CountRunning)+"");
                        float floatCountUser = Float.parseFloat(CountRunning);
                        int positionsUser= Integer.parseInt(position);
                        if(userID.equals(userId)&&j>=9){
                            yourPOsitionTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            String yourDetail="YOU (at "+positionsUser+") with "+CountRunning+" beer";
                            Log.e("yourDetail",yourDetail+"");
                            yourPOsitionTV.setText(yourDetail);
                        }else {
//                            BARENTRY1.add(new BarEntry(fp1, j));
//                            BarEntryLabels1.add("User#" + position);
                            BARENTRY1.add(new BarEntry(floatCountUser, positionsUser));
                            BarEntryLabels1.add("User#" + positionsUser);
                        }
                        Collections.reverse(BARENTRY1);
                    }
                    horizontalBarChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    horizontalBarChart.invalidate();
                    Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY1, "Projects");
                    BARDATA = new BarData(BarEntryLabels1, Bardataset);
                    Bardataset.setColors(new int[]{Color.parseColor("#701112")});
                    horizontalBarChart.setData(BARDATA);
                    horizontalBarChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
                    horizontalBarChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
                    horizontalBarChart.setPinchZoom(false);
                    horizontalBarChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
                    horizontalBarChart.setDescription("");
                    Bardataset.setBarSpacePercent(10f);
                    Legend legend = horizontalBarChart.getLegend();
                    legend.setEnabled(false);
                    horizontalBarChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
                    XAxis xAxis1 = horizontalBarChart.getXAxis();
                    xAxis1.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                    xAxis1.setTextSize(8);
                    xAxis1.setSpaceBetweenLabels(8);
                    xAxis1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#701112"));
                    xAxis1.setTypeface(tf);
                    YAxis leftAxis = horizontalBarChart.getAxisLeft();
                    leftAxis.setEnabled(false);
                    Collections.reverse(BARENTRY1);
                    Collections.reverse(BarEntryLabels1);
                    Log.e("BARENTRY1",BARENTRY1+"");
                    Log.e("BarEntryLabels1",BarEntryLabels1+"");
                } else {
                    String message=resObj.getString("message");
                    apiDetails.logoutCheck(message, getActivity(), mEditPrefs, loginPref);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }

 Please look on to this,Where am doing mistake here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this loop :

```
 for (int j = 0; j < userdataDetailsArray.length(); j++) {
   ....
   ....
}
```

you are using `Collections.reverse(BARENTRY1);` inside the loop. 
Reverse the list once you are done with adding the entries outside the loop.

Also, the reversing should be done before you create the BarData object.
Reverse the list before these lines

```
//reverse here
Collections.reverse(BARENTRY1);
Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY1, "Projects");
BARDATA = new BarData(BarEntryLabels1, Bardataset);
```

Although a better solution would be to parse your response from the other end...
you could change your loop to :

```
for (int j = (userdataDetailsArray.length()-1); j >=0; j++) {
   ....
   ....
}
```

This will eliminate any need of reversing the list.

Comment: Yes,I have done another way.Created ArrayList<Float>counTBarEntryList=new ArrayList<>(); inside for loop  counTBarEntryList.add(floatCountUser);
                            BarEntryLabels1.add(youS + positionsUser); then outside for loop  Collections.reverse(counTBarEntryList);
                    for(int k=0;k<counTBarEntryList.size();k++){
                        float count=counTBarEntryList.get(k);
                        BARENTRY1.add(new BarEntry(count, k));
                    }   done like this

Comment: But that response reverse i had a plan.But it works before that.Anyhow thanx.

Comment: Does BarEntryLabels1 also to be reversed .. to make it work ?